# How do I parse a string to a list of floats using functional style?

Tags: functional-programming, rust

I am trying to parse a string into a list of floating-point values in Rust. I would assume there is a clever way to do this using iterators and `Option`s; however, I cannot get it to ignore the `Err` values that result from failed parse() calls. The Rust tutorial doesn't seem to cover any examples like this, and the documentation is confusing at best.

How would I go about implementing this using the functional-style vector/list operations? Pointers on better Rust style for my iterative implementation would be appreciated as well!

**"Functional"-style**

Panics when it encounters an `Err`

```
input.split(" ").map(|s| s.parse::<f32>().unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

**Iterative-style**

Ignores non-float values as intended

```
fn parse_string(input: &str) -> Vec<f32> {
    let mut vals = Vec::new();
    for val in input.split_whitespace() {
        match val.parse() {
            Ok(v) => vals.push(v),
            Err(_) => (),
        }
    }
    vals
}

fn main() {
    let params = parse_string("1 -5.2  3.8 abc");
    for &param in params.iter() {
        println!("{:.2}", param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) does what you want, transforming the values and filtering out `None`s:

```
input.split(" ").filter_map(|s| s.parse::<f32>().ok()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Note the `ok` method to convert the `Result` to an `Option`.