# Rust inputting 3 integers in one line

Tags: rust

Is there any way to input multiple (assuming we know the amount) integers in Rust like we do in C++?
For example, this is C++ code:

```cpp
int a, b, c;
cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

I know I can read them in tuple and then unpack, but I think there must be a way to do it like in C++.

Comment: What this C++ code is supposed to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read multiple integers from a single line of stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439582/how-do-i-read-multiple-integers-from-a-single-line-of-stdin)

Comment: @Boiethios, This c++ code demonstrates what my Rust code should do. I am new to Rust, so I don't know how to convert it from c++ to rust.