# Why does rust's read_line function use a mutable reference instead of a return value?

Tags: rust

Consider this code to read the user input in rust

```rust
use std::io;
fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("error: unable to read user input");
    println!("{}", input);
}
```

why is there no way to do it like this?

```rust
use std::io;
fn main() {
    let mut input = io::stdin()
        .read_line()
        .expect("error: unable to read user input");
    println!("{}", input);
}
```

it would be more convenient to other languages

Comment: If you need, you can easly write a function that does what you want. Moreover, you can do it by using `read_line`, but you can't make the other way around.

Answer (score 18):

TL;DR The closest you have is `lines()`, and the reason `read_line` works like it does is efficiency. The version that uses `lines()` looks like this:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    // get next line from stdin and print it
    let input = io::stdin().lock().lines().next().unwrap().expect("IO error");
    println!("{}", input);
}
```

In general, `read_line()` is not designed for use in small interactive programs; there are [better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63580989/1600898) to implement those.

The [`read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) method comes from the generic [`io::BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) trait, and its primary use is reading input, typically redirected from files or other programs, and possibly coming in large quantities. When processing large amounts of data, it is advantageous to *minimize* the number of allocations performed, which is why `read_line` is designed to reuse an existing string. A typical pattern would be:

```
let mut line = String::new();
while input.read_line(&mut line)? != 0 {
    // do something with line
    ...
    line.clear();
}
```

The number of (re-)allocations is kept minimal, as `line` will grow only as needed to accommodate the input lines. Once a typical size is reached, allocations will become very rare, and once the largest line is read, they will disappear altogether. If `read_line()` supported the "convenient" interface, then the above loop would indeed look nicer - for example:

```
while let Some(line) = read_new_line(some_input)? {
    // process the line
    ...
}
```

...but would require a new allocation and deallocation for each line. In throw-away or learning programs this can be perfectly fine, but `BufRead` is intended as a building block for *efficient* IO, so its `read_line` method favors performance over convenience.