# How do I iterate over the lines of a (huge) gzipped file?

Tags: rust

So, I am trying to perform a sort of line-oriented operation on a gz compressed file bigger than available RAM, so reading it first into a string is excluded. The question is, how to do it in rust ( short of `gunzip file.gz|./my-rust-program`)?

My current solution is based on `flate2` and a bunch of buffered readers:

```rust
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::fs::File;
use flate2::bufread::GzDecoder as BufGzDecoder;
fn main() {
    let mut fname = "path_to_a_big_file.gz";
    let f = File::open(fname).expect("Ooops.");
    let bf = BufReader::new(f); // Here's the first reader so I can plug data into BufGzDecoder.
    let br = BufGzDecoder::new(bf); // Yep, here. But, oops, BufGzDecoder has not lines method,
                                    // so try to stick it into a std BufReader.
    let bf2 = BufReader::new(br); // What!? This works!? Yes it does.
    // After a long time ...
    eprintln!("count: {}",bf2.lines().count());
    // ... the line count is here.
}
```

To put the above into words, I noticed I cannot plug a file straight into the `flate2::bufread::GzDecoder`, so I first created the `std::io::BufReader` instance which is compatible with the constructor method of the former. But, I did not see any useful iterator associated with `flate2::bufread::GzDecoder`, so I built another `std::io::BufReader` on top of it. Surprisingly, that worked, I got my `Lines` iterator and it read the whole file in just over a minute on my machine, but feels like it's overly verbose and a inelegant as well as possibly inefficient (more worried about this part).

Comment: Before timing it, did you make sure to compile with optimizations?

Comment: @vallentin Yeah, in fact I run that thing in tests and then `cargo test --release`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each *"buffer-inducing"* step described in the question is necessary here.

1. The GZip decoder implementation requires a buffered reader as part of the decoding process. The buffer will be holding compressed data, through which new-line delimitation is not possible due to how GZip works.
2. The second `BufReader` will then be used to identify the line separation pattern and accurately return complete lines of text.

However, there is a shortcut for the first one. The `flate2` crate provides [`read::GzDecoder`](https://docs.rs/flate2/1.0.19/flate2/read/struct.GzDecoder.html), which takes a regular reader and automatically employs buffered reading on it.

```
use flate2::read::GzDecoder;

let reader = BufReader::new(GzDecoder::new(file));
```

With this done, the recommended means of improving efficiency is to ensure that the program is built with the right profile (*release* mode) and to reuse the same String value for each line by using `read_line` instead of the `lines()` iterator, thus reducing the number of memory allocations.

See also:

- [Read large files line by line in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882329/read-large-files-line-by-line-in-rust)
- [What's the de-facto way of reading and writing files in Rust 1.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192956/whats-the-de-facto-way-of-reading-and-writing-files-in-rust-1-x)
- [Why does rust's read_line function use a mutable reference instead of a return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63627687)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Btw, I did not notice any speedup from replacing the lines iterator construct with read_line based solution. I guess this only becomes apparent when the lines are long enough. I have millions of shortish lines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just need to mention that "lines" method calls "read_line" function under the hood by implementing the "Iterator" trait: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/io/mod.rs.html#2808-2810

Answer (score 0):

Some gzip files may have multiple members, see [flate2 documentation](https://docs.rs/flate2/latest/flate2/index.html#about-multi-member-gzip-files). In that case the line iterator will only iterate through the first results and stop unexpectedly (see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71239703/flate2-gzdecoder-not-reading-the-whole-file)). You may want to use a `MultiGzDecoder` to avoid that problem:

```rust
use flate2::read::MultiGzDecoder;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

let file = File::open("path_to_a_big_file.gz").expect("Ooops.");
let reader = BufReader::new(MultiGzDecoder::new(file));

for line in reader.lines() {
    //do something
}
```